# MSAL and Angular2 Azure B2C redirect problems

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I'm using the MSAL library to authenticate to Azure B2C within an Angular5 app. I have MS and Google accounts and local email configured as providers and they all work happily to get the initial token. Which then works against my dotnet core WebAPI backend via the JWT provider nugget package.

I'm not sure how I'm meant to renew the token though, calling the `acquireTokenSilent` function of the MSAL library causes the Microsoft and Google provider tokens to redirect back to Azure then back to my app  (not desirable in a SPA app). The local email one throws an error about state but doesn't redirect, I'm less concerned about that though.

A number of the sample apps says [Silent renewing of access tokens is not supported by all social identity providers](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp) but doesn't expand on exactly which ones...

Is there a means of using MSAL to get replacement tokens against B2C without a full redirect?

```
this.app.acquireTokenSilent(this.config.b2cScopes)
      .then((newToken) => {
        if (newToken) {
          console.log(`got new token ${token}`);
          return newToken;

        }
        else {
          console.log('went bang');
          //presumably this blewup...
        }
      })
      .catch((fail) => {
        console.error(fail);
      });
```

Calling this function is causing the redirect. Initally, this requests to `login.microsoftonline` to get the open-id configuration. Then it requests
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=token&scope={url + scope name} openid profile&state=9c23e002-a07c-4adb-a7fd-db5400f2b8ee&nonce=0ed5c352-d363-4e5e-bd40-4dc10936361f&client_info=1&x-client-SKU=MSAL.JS&x-client-Ver=0.1.5&client-request-id=3889aaeb-4b47-4726-9ef0-e4e3c73ea1e5&prompt=none&domain_req=ba2006a0-9352-424d-81b5-f2df33157082&login_req=213613d5-8217-4db9-8419-60441a5b512f-b2c_1_signup&domain_hint=organizations`

Which 302's around to `login.live.com` with a response `JavaScript required to sign in`. I'm then dumped back into my app without a new token and no real idea of why its upset other than a suspicion the wrong flow is being used and B2C is trying to obtain a new token via an interactive route.

Scope wise the B2C tenant has the `openid` and `offline_access` provisioned by default and against the application `user_impersonation` (was there by default) and a single new scope called `read`. I'm sending those scopes in my request `this.config.b2cscopes`. `openid` and `profile` MSAL appears to add by itself.

Comment: That doesn’t seen right to me as you are getting access to tokens from B2C.  Must be something I don’t understand... asked them to update their docs: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/7531

Comment: cool, it would be helpful to know whats going on. I've since my progress on silent reauth at the expense of my aspnet core webapi no longer accepting the tokens. what a time to be alive.